# I can't make sense of Prenex Normal Form in this case, can anyone help?

Tags: first-order-logic

So, I'm self-studying logic, and the Prenex Normal form just doesn't quite make sense to me in this specific example I came up with. So I just want to see if I'm doing something wrong.

Suppose the domain of discourse is the natural numbers. We can then state the principle of induction as

$$(\forall k(\phi(0) \land (\phi(k) \rightarrow \phi(k+1))) \rightarrow \forall n (\phi(n)),$$

Where $\phi$ is some statement (with minor restrictions relating to freeness or boundness of variables).

So, if my understanding is correct, in prenex normal form the first for all becomes there exists, and the second forall stays forall. There are two possible orders in  which we can take these out, but neither looks correct to me.

The first is

$$\exists k \forall n ((\phi(0) \land (\phi(k) \rightarrow \phi(k+1))) \rightarrow \phi(n))$$

and the second is

$$\forall n \exists k ((\phi(0) \land (\phi(k) \rightarrow \phi(k+1))) \rightarrow \phi(n)).$$

The problem is that obviously neither of these are true. For the first one, no matter what value of $k$ you pick, the implication clearly won't hold for all $n$, and for the second one, $n=2$ is a counterexample (in fact, $n = 1$ or $0$ are the only cases it actually works).

So, is there some sort of exception on how to convert to prenex normal form that I've happened to hit or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your conversions are correct and are logically equivalent to the original statement.

---

> The problem is that obviously neither of these are true. For the first one, no matter what value of $k$ you pick, the implication clearly won't hold for all $n$

Why not? Why do you think this is so clear?

---

> for the second one, $n=2$ is a counterexample

Really? Plugging in $n=2$, I get

$$\exists k((\phi(0)\land(\phi(k)\to \phi(k+1)))\to\phi(2))$$

why would this be a counterexample?

Comment: Well, okay, we can break it down:

If k = 0, the implication only holds for n=0 or 1.

If k isn't 0, I don't see how it holds for any non-zero value of n.

So... can you give me a specific value of k (say k = 5), where just from knowing a property holds for 0, and that *if* a property hold for 5, then it holds for six, I suddenly know it holds for all natural numbers?

Comment: @kabelabel What are you "breaking down" here? The first one?

Comment: Ah. I've just got it.

Yeah, thanks for the answer. I forgot that a fals statement implies anything

Comment: @kabelabel Yup, that's the trick. For me, it's really hard to wrap my head around the fact that $(\forall x: A)\to B$ is equivalent to $\exists x:(A\to B)$. My brain keeps screaming that that just can't be right, but it is, and it is precisely because picking some $x$ such that $A$ is false still means $A\to B$ is true :)